Aerodynamic model of phonation
Someone in a webinar said that there are scientific papers explaining how the Bernoulli effect is not responsible for the phonation of the voice. They also said that the aerodynamic model of phonation is well understood.
I would like to read up about this, but am lacking the name of the theory and relevant papers. Does anyone know?

Martin: I work with acoustics. So the idea that the Bernoulli effect has [any effect is] a misconception. In some simplified settings, it has been explained as the mechanism behind how a flow of air can be chopped off and accelerate the folds and the accelerator and so on. But if you started carefully, the Bernoulli effect cannot explain [phonation]. So there are papers on that.
Jack: So I think we can forget that concept at all. Yeah, I think the whole aerodynamic model of phonation is kind of in question.
Martin: Well, it is well understood, but it cannot be explained as the Bernoulli effect. So [that is] how to get a self-sustaining vibration. So Bernoulli effect has been used to motivate a sustained production of air. And you can do experiments with that in tubes and so on and do else of it, but it's not the Bernoulli effect. It's other effects. It's complicated. I will not go into that. No, it's not the Bernoulli effect. It has to do with impedance, the response of what happens in the vocal tract. Or it has to do with, you can also get a self-sustained by having a [vertical] wave in the folds. That also [explains] self-sustaining oscillations.


https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=Bernoulli+Effect+aerodynamic+model+of+phonation
